# unresponsive UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I implemented an `UISearchBar` to a `UIViewController` and i Added all the necessary *Delegates* to make it functional, the problem is that the `UISearchBar` becomes sometimes unresponsive and whatever  i tape in iPhone Keypad doesn't Appear on the `UISearchBar`, especially when i push a new `UIViewController` and then i pop it back. what's the problem with my code

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {

 IBOutlet UISearchBar * SearchBar ;   

}


-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    SearchBar.delegate = self ;
}


- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    if(SearchBar.text.length < 3){

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                        message:@"Votre recherche doit contenir 3 caractères minimum"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }else{
        self.Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self getData];

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried setting a breakpoint in your method?

Comment: Also you dont need     SearchBar.delegate = self ;
Doing that in viewDidLoad is enough

Comment: check you main thread is blocking or not. If you do a network call on main thread your app will freeze

Comment: what do you mean by saying breakpoint ?

Comment: http://earthlingsoft.net/ssp/blog/graphics/XCodeDebugVariables.png